# Extreme training for civilians

Tags: training, self-defense

I am a civilian who would love to get trained in a similar way that special forces such as SEALs, do. More specifically, I want to:

- be able to defend myself and others with bare hands or with any tool available at the moment against various types of attack,
- be able to survive in extreme conditions (in water, desert, jungle, mountains, etc.),
- gain extreme mental strength,
- get into great physical shape with functional strength (i.e. not just gain muscle but also strength and stamina),
- be able to provide at least basic first aid,
- know what to do / how to react in dangerous situations (e.g. an attacker in a subway full of people, etc.)

I believe gaining the above skills would allow me to live my life to the fullest and really take the responsibility for all my actions. However, I do not want to enter militia.

**Is there anything like this available for civilians** (regardless of location - I am willing to travel)? Now I could possibly find separate courses for **some** of the things above, but I would prefer an intense 1 or 2 month camp with everything included.

The closest I found so far is SEALFIT programme, but it only takes 2 days which is obviously not enough for all the things specified above.

Comment: You are highly unlikely to find a civilian course that will teach any of this in a way that will stay with you for life. You state you don't want to enter a militia but that might be your only choice - some military special forces do allow civilians to attempt the selection course.

Comment: Become an ultimate warrior in two months or your money back! Come on, man. These things take a life time to learn. Stop looking for the quick/easy route. Start working hard. In 10 years when you're a beast you'll look back and laugh at how ridiculous you were to assume one could learn any one of those things so quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not martial arts related.

Comment: "An intense 1 or 2 month camp"...the skills you are describing take many years to master. All a camp will do is teach you to survive the camp.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a unicorn.

None of the skills you want will be tough effectively in a few months. It will take years to develop them and daily practice to keep them honed. Unless you plan to be a member of an elite military or police or rescue responder force, you are wasting your time. If not, those organisations will teach you all you need to know.

Check [no nonsense self defense](https://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/) as it contains many good resources if you want to learn self defence and will dispel of a lot of the nonsense idiocy you might have heard.

Keeping fit, first aid, and survival are all off topic here. All three are vast subjects where many charlatans will take your money for fake, incomplete, and dangerous courses. All of them take years of learning and practice to become efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> be able to defend myself and others with bare hands or with any tool available at the moment against various types of attack

Try some Krav Maga courses. It's supposed to teach you primarily aggression. If you've never fought before, keep in mind - Jason Bourne is not going to happen. You'll get punched, especially if there is more than one opponent. I know krav maga has techniques against multiple opponents, but cannot say anything more, cause I didn't train it properly yet.

> be able to survive in extreme conditions (in water, desert, jungle, mountains, etc.)

Maybe some survival camps? My friend reads some survival guides, gets ready and just goes into a forest in the middle of the winter, builds a shed and sleeps there. He learned a lot, since a couple of times his shelter got flushed with water. (Built it in a den)

> gain extreme mental strength

The real answer is I don't think you'll be able to have a normal life with going to work, while someone mentally breaking you.

> get into great physical shape with functional strength (i.e. not just gain muscle but also strength and stamina)

Talk to a personal trainer, or search the internet and hit the gym. This one is easy to find.

> be able to provide at least basic first aid

First aid courses

> know what to do / how to react in dangerous situations (e.g. an attacker in a subway full of people, etc.)

My friend trains Krav Maga. He said they have "practical lessons" later on. They go on a bus, and one person from the group is going to attack someone else. Everybody needs to be ready.

There are some boot camps in which ex-military train civilians. But they are not the proper military training, mostly because most of the civilians just want to ***feel*** they are ready for a situation.

Keep in mind, no one will just give you the knowledge. They will show you the path, and you'll have to work to get where you want to be.